# What is the equivalent of "I am risking my head to say" when expressing a different opinion?

Tags: expressions, idiom-requests, euphemisms

When you are in a minority, say most of the people prefer A to B, if you want to assert your support for B, you can have different moods, e.g.,

(1) brave and combative: "I love B so much more than A, come sue me!!"

(2) cautious I: "Am I the only one supporting B?"

(3) cautious II: In my native language, it is common to say "I am risking my head to say I am for B, not A".

So my question is what's the English equivalent or alternative to "I am risking my head to say" in 3) cautious II above? Thanks.

Answer (score 38):

> You are sticking your neck out!

**stick (one's) neck out**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stick+neck+out)

> To personally assume or expose oneself to some risk, danger, or
>   responsibility; to imperil oneself or put oneself in harm's way.

The figurative interpretation is you are taking a risk, as you risk having it chopped off!

Answer (score 11):

As FumbleFingers answered in a comment to the question,

> *I know I'm **going out on a limb** by expressing my support for B rather than A* (figuratively, on a tree branch that might not be strong enough to support my weight).

(I wrote this in case the comment gets deleted by a mod.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88862/discussion-on-answer-by-jol-what-is-the-equivalent-of-i-am-risking-my-head-to-s).

Answer (score 10):

There is a similar idiom in the form of:

***They'll (probably) hang me for this, but ...***

Some examples from the web:

> I know hotel and restaurant owners will hang me for this, but only visit them if you can afford it ...
>
> I know pros would want to hang me for this, but the problem is that ...
>
> Somebody will probably hang me for this, but anyway: I am using the v700 and I think it is a very good solution ...

And from Google Books:

> I do realize that what I am stating here is not going to bode well with my fellow Christians who may want to hang me for this, but I find it very difficult to not respect a leader who stared down the most powerful army of the region ...
>
> *Survival: The Ultimate Mission* by Robert Skaf

Answer (score 8):

***to risk your neck***

> If you say that someone is risking their neck, you mean they are doing something very dangerous, often in order to achieve something.

[-Collins online](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-risk-your-neck)

or

"It's (risking) my neck to come out for candidate A"

Comment: Risking your neck generally implies *doing* something dangerous, not *saying* something that'll make you unpopular.

Comment: Erm..but in most of the world, given the present political climate, (not USA, not Europe...think Russia, Africa, middle east), expressing an opinion can be a _very_ dangerous action. @Marthaª

Comment: Yes, I know, but that's clearly not the context the OP is talking about.

Answer (score 3):

In English, it's also common to say "I'm risking my neck" as well. But that would be for something more serious than just being a lone dissenter about a minor thing. It's more likely in that case to say "I'm sticking my neck out".

Examples of the terms and contexts they might be used in:

- If I found out that the company I worked for was a mafia front
  company, and I wore a wire for the cops to gather evidence, I'm
  **risking my neck**.
- If I am the only person who thinks that *The Star Wars Holiday
  Special* is a classic, and I interrupt friends who are making fun of
  it to defend its merits, I'm **sticking my neck out**.
- In keeping with the *Star Wars* theme, there is a line where C-3PO
  says to R2-D2, "Why I should **stick my neck out** for you is quite
  beyond my capacity."

Comment: It's not uncommon - but in different circumstances and with a different meaning, e.g. "I'm risking my neck to help you".

Comment: In the majority of the countries in the world (sad to say) but expressing a dissenting political opinion _is actually risking your neck_.

Answer (score 3):

As Wmbuch answered in a comment to the question,

> You might also begin with **Don't shoot me, but...**

(I wrote this in case the comment gets deleted by a mod.)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to "risking my neck", mentioned in another answer, I suggest "risking life and limb" which is also idiomatic and means the same.

> [**"risk life and limb"**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/risk+one%27s+neck) -  Take dangerous chances, as in
>
> - "There he was on the roof, risking life and limb to rescue the kitten."
> - "I'm sure it's thrilling, but I'd rather not risk life and limb just for a bit of an adrenaline rush."

Edit - After reading the comments, I must admit my answer doesn't really fit the bill as it usually means physical harm but is only rarely, if ever, used as a metaphor.

Comment: Would I be risking life and limb by pointing out that this is a completely different sense than the one I went out on a limb with in my comment to the question? :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers   No, you wouldn't.  But I'd risk my neck to say it's idiomatic and seems like a good fit.

Comment: Which do you value more? Your life, your limb, or your neck? :) It's funny people are always willing to say *I'd bet my life [X is true]*, but no-one ever bets their neck or limb.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Literally, the expression doesn't make much sense because if you lose your life, your limbs will be gone too.  Then again, the neck is a vital part of our body, without it we're dead.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I've heard people bet their ass, though.

Comment: Haha - you bet your ***sweet bippy!*** Or can only shapely women raise the stakes that high?

Comment: I personally have only encountered "risk life & limb" used for instances of risk of physical injury, not metaphorically for "social" risk or losing face. The thefreedictionary.com link only has examples of this phrase being used for physical risk. "risking one's neck" can be metaphorical, but the 2 idioms don't seem fully substitutable.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think either Rowan or Martin were shapely women, although I think they often said it in reference to Goldie Hawn.

Comment: ...not sure if "bippy" referred to the upper portions of a woman's body...I always thought it meant ass. Besides that, Goldie is not generally known for having a voluptuous body. @FumbleFingers,

Comment: This has the same problem as "risking your neck": like FumbleFingers said, it's used for a risk of physical injury, not social ostracism.

Comment: @Cascabel: As it happens, I just watched a couple of Goldie Hawn movies with my twenty-something daughter last week, and we both agreed she had a real shapely ass!

Answer (score 2):

While I like [lbf](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/277355/lbf)'s [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/482819/330443), another option would be to say "I'm putting my ___ on the line" (where "___" could be "reputation", or it could be "ass").

See [The Free Dictionary's entry for "put on the line"](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/put+on+the+line):

> expose to a chance of loss or damage; "We risked losing a lot of money in this venture"; "Why risk your life?"; "She laid her job on the line when she told the boss that he was wrong"

Comment: FWIW I'm pretty sure it's okay to spell out 'Ass' or 'Butt' in the context of your answer here.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly less common variant of *risking my neck*, which might also match the OP's intention is:

> **I'm putting my neck on the line**
>
> > https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-your-neck-on-the-line

I can't immediately see any explanation of its origin online, but I guess the *line* implies a train line. Or ... was there a line at the foot of madame la guillotine?

Answer (score 0):

I think “**I'm risking my head to say…**”, as in the question, would be perfectly well understood by all English speakers.

That exact wording may not be as common as in the OP's native language, but it's similar enough to other common phrases (as per other answers), and doesn't sound at all odd in English.

So maybe it doesn't really *need* an alternative or equivalent after all?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My intention was to learn if a native English speaker were to be in such a situation, what would s/he be using.

Comment: @swoopin_swallow using 'head', despite it being understood, is not idiomatic English (does not come naturally, native speakers would just not say it that way).

Comment: @Mitch Were you trying to reply to gidds answer? What you said agrees with my comment.

Comment: @swoopin_swallow I was replying to you. You said in your comment "My intention was to learn ...what they would use " and my comment  says you would not use 'head'. There is nothing to agree with in your comment because it is asking a question rather than making a statement.

Comment: @Mitch I am confused. In my comment I indicated I want to know what a native speaker would use, i.e., I know "risking head" is only a proper way to say it in my native language, I would not use "head" when I speak English. Wasn't it what you wanted me to know?

Comment: @swoopin_swallow I am likewise confused. Gidds' answer seems to think 'head' is OK; your first comment asks what a native would say, implying that maybe 'head' is OK or maybe it is not; then my comment says 'head' is not OK. That's all I'm saying. You may have known that 'head' is not OK already, but that was not clear from your words.

Comment: In my experience as an English speaker, in English 'neck' is more common then head here.

Comment: @Mitch I thought I was clear I don't think 'head' is OK. I probably should've added 'But' to "my intention was ..." in the immediate comment after gidds' answer. That way maybe you would not have thought I was not clear.